# Cannot solve FINE_LOCATION?

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am trying out a few things on Android Studio, and when I typed in:

```
if (pm.checkPermission(permission.FINE_LOCATION, getPackageName()) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
            alertbox();
}
```

It was strange because I included asking permission in the manifest file, and FINE_LOCATION is, I believe, a predefined symbol. So I am really confused on how it came up with the error,

"Cannot Resolve FINE_LOCATION".

What is a possible cause for this? Did I stuff something up real bad?

Thank you!

Comment: What is `permission` in the code above? In order to be valid it would have to be an object or class with a field `FINE_LOCATION`.

Comment: here permission is android.Manifest.permission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure this is the solution

But change your code to

change permission.FINE_LOCATION to permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION i.e.

```
if (pm.checkPermission(permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, getPackageName()) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {

            alertbox();
}
```

Comment: It WAS the solution. Thanks!